# How can I unit test that Windsor can resolve Asp.net MVC3 controller dependencies?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, castle-windsor

Currently I have Windsor controller factory that is working well.  However, I am changing my controllers a bit and having Windsor instantiate more data for controllers.  I forgot to update my Installer class and it failed.

Thus, I realized this is a perfect instance for unit testing, so every time I run my unit tests it will verify that Windsor is set up correctly.

Thus I created the following unit test:

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void Windsor_Can_Resolve_HomeController_Dependencies()
    {
        // Setup
        WindsorContainer container = new WindsorContainer();

        // Act
        HomeController controller = (HomeController)container.Kernel.Resolve(typeof(HomeController));
    }
```

This is exactly the same code that exists in my `WindsorControllerFactory.GetControllerInstance()` method so I am not sure why this isn't working.  When this runs I get:

```
Test method MyApp.Tests.Controllers.HomeControllerTest.Windsor_Can_Resolve_HomeController_Dependencies threw exception: 
Castle.MicroKernel.ComponentNotFoundException: No component for supporting the service MyApp.Controllers.HomeController was found
```

I'm not sure how to tackle this.  The only thing I can think of is that since it's in my test project, and not my Asp.net MVC project it might not be automatically picking up my `CommandAndQueryInstaller` class, which contains all of my windsor type registration.

Any advice for unit testing windsor dependency configuration?

Comment: The questioner has asked a question that follows this one if you're using the `PerWebResquestLifeStyle`: http://stackoverflow.com/q/5772497/114029 Make sure you check it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are creating a new WindsorContainer in your setup and not registering any dependencies in the container. You'll need to run your IWindsorInstallers in order to populate the container.

```
[TestMethod]
public void Windsor_Can_Resolve_HomeController_Dependencies()
{
    // Setup
    WindsorContainer container = new WindsorContainer();
    container.Install(FromAssembly.Containing<HomeController>());

    // Act
    HomeController controller = container.Resolve<HomeController>();
}
```

Note that you don't have to access the kernel. You can use container.Resolve<T>(), which also takes care of the cast internally.

Comment: Aha, I knew I was looking for something like that, I just couldn't find it in my code base.  Thanks!