# How can I unit test my controller to make sure Windsor can resolve dependencies when using PerWebRequestLifestyle

Tags: c#, unit-testing, castle-windsor

I have the following unit test in my application:

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void Windsor_Can_Resolve_HomeController_Dependencies()
    {
        // Setup
        WindsorContainer container = new WindsorContainer();
        container.Install(FromAssembly.Containing<HomeController>());

        // Act
        container.Kernel.Resolve(typeof(HomeController));
    }
```

The point of this is to make sure I don't have any windsor configuration issues that I won't realize until I access an action on that controller.  The problem is that all my object registrations are registered as `PerWebRequestLifestyle` so I don't get issues with my Entity Framwork Data Context being shared across web requests (which causes errors when multiple actions are run).

However, whenever I run this unit test I get the following exception:

System.InvalidOperationException: HttpContext.Current is null. PerWebRequestLifestyle can only be used in ASP.Net

How can I go about testing this scenario without changing the lifestyle of my object registration commands?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I don't know if you can use the PerWebRequestLifestyle outside of ASP.NET (MVC) (I don't think you can), but you can use an [IContributeComponentModelConstruction to modify the lifestyle of the components when they are registered](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/04/26/ChangingWindsorLifestylesAfterTheFact.aspx).

This would enable you to (integration) test the container without modifying any of your Installers.

Comment: This didn't work for me, however this SO answer did http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5781599/testing-castle-windsor-component-with-perwebrequest-lifestyle