# Castle Windsor issue with NUnit testing - Instance not initialize properly

Tags: asp.net-mvc, unit-testing, dependency-injection, nunit, castle-windsor

In MVC application we are using windsor container and NUnit testing.
Following is the windsor registration code:

```
  public void Install(IWindsorContainer container, IConfigurationStore store)
    {
        container.Register(Component.For<HttpContextBase>().LifeStyle.PerWebRequest.UsingFactoryMethod(() => new HttpContextWrapper(HttpContext.Current)));
        container.Register(Component.For<IHttpContextBaseWrapper>().ImplementedBy<HttpContextBaseWrapper>().LifestylePerWebRequest());
        container.Register(Component.For<IWebUtility>().ImplementedBy<WebUtility>().LifestylePerWebRequest());
        container.Register(Component.For<IExceptionReporter>().ImplementedBy<ExceptionReporter>().LifestylePerWebRequest());
        container.Register(Component.For<ICacheProvider>().ImplementedBy<WebCacheProvider>().LifestylePerWebRequest());
        container.Register(Component.For<IEmailNotifier>().ImplementedBy<EmailNotifier>().LifestylePerWebRequest());
        container.Register(Component.For<IUserStore<ApplicationUser>>().ImplementedBy<ApplicationUserStore<ApplicationUser>>().LifestylePerWebRequest());
        container.Register(Component.For<ApplicationUserManager>().ImplementedBy<ApplicationUserManager>().LifestylePerWebRequest());
    }
```

It works fine with normal web request(from browser) but not working wile calling controller methods from NUnit test cases. It gives following error while resolving service instances.

Looks like you forgot to register the http module Castle.MicroKernel.Lifestyle.PerWebRequestLifestyleModule
To fix this add

```
<add name="PerRequestLifestyle" type="Castle.MicroKernel.Lifestyle.PerWebRequestLifestyleModule, Castle.Windsor" />
```

to the `<httpModules>` section on your `web.config`.
If you plan running on IIS in Integrated Pipeline mode, you also need to add the module to the `<modules>` section under `<system.webServer>`.
Alternatively make sure you have `Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35` assembly in your GAC (it is installed by ASP.NET MVC3 or WebMatrix) and Windsor will be able to register the module automatically without having to add anything to the config file.

i tried putting

```
<add name="PerRequestLifestyle" type="Castle.MicroKernel.Lifestyle.PerWebRequestLifestyleModule, Castle.Windsor" />
```

in app.config/web.config. But found same error.

Comment: Is `HttpContext` going to exist when running the code outside ASP.Net hosting, i.e. in a unit test?

Comment: yes, Exactly HttpContext is null.

Comment: Then you'll need to provide a fake context or use a test host.

Comment: However, a fake `HttpContext` will not resolve the Winsdor lifestyle issue as I think that's handled at the `HttpModule` level. Take a look at this (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5781599/testing-castle-windsor-component-with-perwebrequest-lifestyle). You can alter the lifestyle of your components so that its appropriate for testing.